# How to install "Html Agility Pack" in my C# project?

Tags: c#, project, addition

I'm a PHP Programmer, and totally new to C#. I have downloaded the Html Agility Pack from http://html-agility-pack.net  now I need to add the assembly to the project, I think...

How can I add this package to my project?

Best Regards,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use HTML Agility pack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use HTML Agility pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should have a prebuilt assembly somewhere (ends in .dll) just right click on your project and "Add Reference" and browse to that and include the relevant namespaces.

Previous question - [How to use HTML Agility pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack)

Answer (score 4):

Open the References node in under your project in Visual Studio.  You'll see a list of referenced assemblies.  Right-click the References folder and select Add Reference.  You can then select from the list of .NET assemblies, or Browse and find its location.